# Issue with Discord.js avatarURL

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

.avatarURL for discord.js is not displaying any image.

I'm trying to make a command for my discord bot that lets someone ping another and have the bot display their profile picture. I quickly homed in on .avatarURL being the solution for this, but it doesn't seem to be displaying any image at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}showpfp`)) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle(tMember.displayName + "'s Profile Picture").setImage(tMember.avatarURL).setColor('#add8e6')

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
```

after typing in command `_showpfp @user` the bot will respond with

```
user's Profile Picture
```

and thats it...

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post, but tmember is
let tMember = message.mentions.members.first();

Comment: You can edit the question to include this information. It's best to not create comments for additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `tMember` doesn't have a property `avatarURL`. In your comment you say that you get the value of `tMember` by doing `message.mentions.members.first()`, however `message.mentions.members` is a collection of [GuildMembers](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). A GuildMember doesn't have a property `avatarURL`.

However, the class [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) does have the property `avatarURL`. Therefor you need to fetch the member as an instance of User first. Luckily for you, the class GuildMember has a property [`.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) which does just that.

So the fix for your problem is to change the parameter of the `setImage` to `tMember.user.avatarURL`, as can be seen below.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}showpfp`)) {
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle(tMember.displayName + "'s Profile Picture").setImage(tMember.user.avatarURL).setColor('#add8e6')

  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue perfectly, I appreciate the help.